# Display all rather than a screen at a time with SonicWALL CLI SHOW command?

Tags: networking, security, command-line-interface, sonicwall

With the SonicWALL Command Line Interface one can list address-objects using the `show` command.

```
show address-objects mac
```

Then it will display a screen full followed by `--MORE--`. Return displays the next line, a space displays the next screen. Is there a way to specify the rest rather than just a screen at a time?

Comment: I don't now anything about sonicwall, but `more` is used as the *"pager"* and if sonicwall behaves like most *NIX environments you might be able to override that by setting the `PAGER` environment variable to something like  `/bin/cat` if you don't want paging (or to `/bin/less` if you want advanced paging)

Comment: For Cisco it's (mostly) `terminal length 0` to disable breaks. For HP it's (mostly) `screen-length disable`. Look in the Sonicwall CLI reference for something similar.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this..

Login into SonicWALL CLI then:

```
cli screen length session 1600
cli screen width session 2560
```

or

```
no cli pager session
```

This works for me on firmware 6.2.

Comment: I was scripting the ssh session since there's no easy way to script the web panel and I had previously just made an expect script to send a return whenever it reaches `--more--` but this is leaps and bounds better.

Comment: You can use paramiko lib to avoid the --more-- or just set the output session size at Sonicwall CLI, then it.will output all text whitout pagination.

Comment: just wanted to let you know old info os still good info.
no cli pager session just saved my day, thanks :-)